# Creating heatmap of US locations changing over time with python

Tags: python, heatmap, subplot, plotly

The data I have is a set of occurrences of a general event in various US states for a given set of years. All I care about illustrating is 1) the year of the occurrence(s), and 2) the location (state) of the occurrence(s).
I am using state capital latitude and longitudes as the location of each point plotted, and want each point on the map to have a color corresponding to the number of occurrences in that state, in that year. I would like to create a map subplot; essentially create one of these maps for each year of available data and plot all those maps together to visualize the change in location of events over time.

So far, the closest thing I have found I can do is create a scattergeo plot using python and plotly (i.e. the figure at the bottom of this: https://plot.ly/python/map-subplots-and-small-multiples/ ), which gives me the desired map subplot over time, but I cannot figure out how to make each of the submaps into a heat map, rather than a simple scatterplot. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! As you can probably tell I'm a python noob, but I hope I was able to make my problem clear!